# How to change Jenkins config directory?

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

I deployed my `Jenkins` to `Tomcat 7`. At that time, my tomcat was running under user `root` (on `CentOS 7`). The Jenkins config was placed in `/root/.jenkins`.

Now I want to run my Tomcat as a different user. The startup resulted in errors obviously because it couldn't access root's home directory.

How can I switch the Jenkins config from root to somewhere accessible by the new user under which Jenkins runs?

Answer (score 1):

As [its official documents](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) says, you have the following three options to change jenkins home directory:

- Set "JENKINS_HOME" environment variable to the new home directory before launching the servlet container.
- Set "JENKINS_HOME" system property to the servlet container.
- Set JNDI environment entry "JENKINS_HOME" to the new directory.

You could try option `#1` or `#2` before starting Tomcat in a different user, and of course make sure the access permission of new jenkins home directory correct.